# How to use eventlistener on navigation EXCEPT on 2 things

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller, kendo-ui

I have two kendo menus where I want the page to be reloaded.  However, per request from our client, they don't want the user to be able to click the back button.  Here's the code I'm using for that:

```
<script>
history.pushState(null, null, 'HomePage');
    window.addEventListener('popstate', function(e) {
            history.pushState(null, null, 'HomePage');
    });
</script>
```

Basically, I want to trigger that event on everything except a a menu item click on these two kendo menus.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put this code in the  section of my MVC project in _layout.cshtml to finally solve the problem.  The only issue I'm still coming across is the right-click back button functionality is still occurring.

Code:

```
    history.pushState(null, null, $(location).attr('href'));
    window.addEventListener('popstate', function () {
        history.pushState(null, null, $(location).attr('href'));
    });
```